# Spree, Ruby On Rails. Question about the employment of the "yield" function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

While reading the spree source code via the official code repository on Github, https://github.com/spree/spree. I couldn't help but notice a strange (at least the first time I see it) usage of the function "yield" on the main loading page of the demo site, as in https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/views/layouts/spree_application.html.erb

The unnamed yield in the body of the page intrigues me, what makes it automatically "yield" the content of the following page: 
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/views/shared/_products.html.erb

In other words what decides on what to be render while using an unnamed yield.

Any clarification will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[spree_application.html.erb](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/views/layouts/spree_application.html.erb) is a main application layout page. This will have all the design common to application/large part of application (One place to make changes sitewide).

the unnamed `yield` will place the content of view which is `related` to current request.

You must have noticed this when you visited home page. Which is `products#index` (Products controller and view index). `root :to => 'products#index'` ([Reference](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/config/routes.rb)).

If you check ([product#index view](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/views/products/index.html.erb)), it renders partials from `shared/_product`

`<%= render "shared/products", :products => @products, :taxon => @taxon %>`

Comment: Hope that clarifies. If not just comment.